# Path in Intellij Vs. Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, intellij-idea

My company is attempting to make a transition from Eclipse to Intellij Idea and I have a (might be silly) question regarding the paths.

I have a library in the root of the eclipse project and a spring configuration file which simply points to it by "folderName/file.txt". It works fine in Eclipse since it recognizes the folder. In IntelliJ however it seems to not pick the folder at all.

I've tried to mark the folder as a resource/test resource folder but it seems to simply take the contents of the folder and dump it directly into the target folder without the folder itself, just the contents.

Is there a way to configure IntelliJ to work with the folder just like in Eclipse? This is important because some are still using Eclipse, some IntelliJ, so we need a solution that will work for both.

Comment: How have you got Eclipse configured? I'd have expected you to want to put those resources in a `resources` folder which was in the build path for Eclipse, rather than the project root being seen as in the build path itself.

Comment: In Eclipse whatever you dump in the root of the project is accessible... No need to configure it as resource. For example if I have a file `folderName/foo.txt` I can do `new File("folderName/foo.txt")` and it will be found.

Comment: If you're using `new File(...)` then that suggests it may just be a working directory issue... but that may well not be appropriate anyway. If the root isn't in the build path, then I expect you'll find that your file isn't being *copied* anywhere as an output. I would normally expect to find such configuration using resources on the classpath instead. But if you *do* want to just use `new File(...)` then you can probably just change the working directory when launching in Idea.

Comment: Since I'm using Idea for less than 24 hours, would you mind elaborating on how to do this? :) Thanks!

Comment: Well I've never used Idea in any serious way at all, so you're ahead of me... but it shouldn't be too hard to find the settings for "where the code is run". Alternatively, I'd suggest that in *both* Idea and Eclipse, you change the structure to have a `resources` folder which includes this folder underneath it, and put that on the output path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing your are using maven since you mention the "target folder"
What happens is that since your imported the project from the maven pom.xml intellij build it by following maven. 
In maven the default project structure is 
[this](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html)

[image]

This in maven everything you copy in the **resources** folder, will be copied to your root classpath. so if you make for 
**resources/myFolder/my.txt** then in the build you will have copied to your classpath **myFolder/my.txt**
Anyway if you are not using maven all you have to do is go to 
**Project structure** (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>) - **Modules** - go to your module - mark the folder that your want to add as **resource**
[image]

Comment: Tried it with no success... Further exploration revealed that `new File("fileName")` goes to the Idea project path, while the source folder and files are being copied to the `git` path. How can I configure the module to go to the git path where all the sources and resources reside?

Comment: If you imported the project with maven and if your maven project does not have anything special configured for the resources then whatever you have in the **/src/man/resources/** folder will be copied to your **/target/classes** folder.

Comment: I want to know how to access the folder like in Eclipse. In Eclipse I have "folderName" in the root project and I can access it via `new File("folderName")`. Is there such a way to configure Idea? I need the tests working in both Eclipse, Idea and production.

Comment: If you want to mix your resource files with your source files the go to the folder that your java class is that you want to add and create the folder there. Cant help you much with eclipse since I have not used it much.

Comment: I'll elaborate: In production I have a folder `production` which contains all I need to run the service, e.g. resources, classes etc all inside packaged and ready. Also I have `folderName` folder which contains some files that I need. The code simply grabs the files via `new File("folderName")`. I need Idea to mimic the same behavior that I have in production - using `new File("folderName")`. The problem that it goes to the project root and no to the git folder where the files are actually stored and copied... There's gotta be a simple way to configure this...

Comment: Cant help more without knowing the intelliJ configuration and project structure

Comment: The project is located under `c:\path\to\IdeaProject\projectName` while the files themselves are pulled from git to `c:\my\git\repo\projectFiles\ ` - two completely different directories. When I do the new File("...") it directs me to `c:\path\to\IdeaProject\projectName` while all the resources are copied to `c:\my\git\repo\projectFiles\target\test-classes`

Comment: This is too specific and I dont know how to help more but if the directory you want to read is copied to the same path your java file is then you should have no problems in your final running code. OK i have an idea. In your **Run/debug configuration** that you use to run your application change the change the **working direcotry** to the one you want (**c:\my\git\repo\projectFiles\target\test-classes**)? This will solve your problem most likely. Play arround with that and you will probably get it

Comment: But I have a problem testing it since my Spring configuration also states directly "folderName"... I need to know how to configure the project/module so the Spring configuration will work in testing time as well as production.

Comment: OK i have an idea. In your Run/debug configuration that you use to run your application change the change the working direcotry to the one you want (c:\my\git\repo\projectFiles\target\test-classes)? This will solve your problem most likely. Play arround with that and you will probably get it